# JAVA StringTokenizer gives random results

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

So, I have the following code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (inputString.trim(), "!=^><~", true);
log.warning(inputString.trim() + " -> " + st.countTokens());
```

The issue am I facing is: for the same inputSring (taking for example the string "@IsForStorage@=Y") most of the times this will produce the next output:

```
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 3
```

But sometimes, this will produce this output:

```
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 2
```

which is obviously very-very-very wrong.

I noticed that if I set up a breakpoint before writing into the log I will get this wrong result almost every time. I also noticed that if I evaluate in Eclipse expressions like *st.countTokens()* while stopped at the breakpoint, the returned value decreases after every evaluation with 1 (in Eclipse and also in my code), getting even to the point where when I hit Run I get the output:

```
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 0
```

The value also decreases if I write in my code multiple calls of *countTokens()* like:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (inputString.trim(), "!=^><~", true); 
log.warning(inputString.trim() + " -> " + st.countTokens());
log.warning(inputString.trim() + " -> " + st.countTokens());
log.warning(inputString.trim() + " -> " + st.countTokens());
```

This will produce sometimes (almost every time in debug mode but also while running) outputs like:

```
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 2
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 1
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 0
```

and sometimes the output is like this:

```
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 3
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 3
@IsForStorage@=Y -> 3
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening!?
I know StringTokenizer is deprecated and should not be used, but I have many old lines of code in my project which are affected by this and are difficult to be replaced.

I am using Java SE 8.0.91 and Java SE 8.0.92. The application runs on Payara 4 server. The code is written in Eclipse MARS 2.

The problem appears when I run my application, but also if I write a simple stand-alone Java application and debug it with Eclipse.

Here is a sample which illustrates perfectly the problem:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String inputString = "@IsForStorage@=Y";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputString.trim(), "!=^<~", >true);
        System.out.println(inputString + " -> " + Integer.toString(st.countTokens()));
        System.out.println(inputString + " -> " + Integer.toString(st.countTokens()));
        System.out.println(inputString + " -> " + Integer.toString(st.countTokens()));
    } 
}
```

Comment: I suspect your situation is *not* as simple as you think. Can you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: My guess is that you also have a watch expression for `st.nextToken()` in your debugger, and that your IDE thus evaluates the value of this expression, which causes the tokenizer to advance its current position, which thus makes the next evaluation of countTokens() return 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: remove the > before the true to make it compile - I really can't reproduce it with either Eclipse or Intellij and java 1.8.0_92, so I hope JB Nizet is right